# Как сделать редирект с HTTPS на HTTP

Tags: apache2

Есть сервер с `Apache2`. Хочу сделать редирект с `httpS` на `http`. Да да, не ослышались. Проблема в том что у меня нет домена, нет `ssl`. Думал в конфиге апача можно прописать, но не работает. То есть хочу чтобы с `https://ip` редиректило на `http://ip`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName 185.179.XXX.XX
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^185\.179\.XXX\.XX$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Никак. Для редиректа с https на http нужен валидный сертификат, а в таком случае в редиректе уже нет никакого смысла

Comment: Ну и вообще странная идея, кто вам будет такие запросы слать?